# Blaze DS 4 libs missing mx.* packages

Tags: apache-flex, jar, blazeds

I'm new to Flex and BlazeDS.

I just set up my environment (Flex 4.6 SDK, Blaze DS 4.01) and I'm wondering where the needed mx.* packages might be found, since I want to import classes, such as mx.messages.Producer / Consumer, in my non-MXML-Project and instanciate them programmatically. Blaze DS API ref says, they are part of the Blaze-WAR but I just can't find them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 0):

The Procuder / Consumer classes are in the mx.messag**ing** package, not mx.messag**e**. They are part of the Flex framework as SWC libraries and are used at Flex compilation time, in order to build your SWF application. They can be deployed in a WAR as RSLs (*Runtime Shared Library*) but you shouldn't use them from this location in your developments: use instead the Flex 4.6 SDK libraries.

As an alternative, you could also use [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org), which are many more features than BlazeDS (asynchronous real-time messaging, data management, code generation tools, etc.) and is fully open-source. See the documentation [here](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.0/docs/reference/en-US/html/index.html) and a detailed comparison between GraniteDS / BlazeDS [here](http://granitedataservices.com/migrating-from-blazeds-to-graniteds/).